# Basic string manipulation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a method, which right now only needs to do an `NSLog` call:

```
(void)methodName:(NSString*)name {
    NSLog(@"hey there, %@", name);
}
```

It says "`Local declaration of 'name' hides instance variable`". What does this mean? How do I construct the string I want?

Comment: Show the rest of the class please.

Comment: Is this method in a class with an instance variable called `name`?

Comment: @vcsjones not really necessary, the error is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you already have a variable called 'name' in your class that includes the methodName method. You might want to change it to look like this:

```
- (void)methodName:(NSString*)theName {
    NSLog(@"hey there, %@", theName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply rename the argument:

```
-(void)methodName:(NSString*)nameParam {
   NSLog(@"hey there, %@", nameParam);
}
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, and for fixing the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using `name` as a property or variable.  Using it as a parameter name in a method is using it twice.

Change the name of your method parameter to something else.

Comment: I think you mean method parameter :)